# moodle - avoid simultaneous grading

Tags: javascript, php, moodle

I'm working on a Moodle install and wondering how I can make it so to  avoid simultaneous grading.  I plan on having multiple evaluators grading  students on multiple courses and want to try and avoid any collisions.

Any recommendations or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use course groups to map evaluators to students.